# Are libc and malloc part of the operating system?

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, malloc, libc

I was having a discussion with a co-worker about malloc, and Was wondering if it is the cases that certain libc calls like malloc are implemented by the operating system?

I always thought that malloc was calling some symbols exposed in "sys" to declare which memory addresses it would use. From what I thought the operating system would allow the program's segmentation to be specified using some os level api... which might similar to:

```
int assign_memory_segmention(size_t start, size_t end);
```

I know my stdlib.h header is part of GNU because of the GPL header... and as GNU have made sure to inform me... they are not Unix. So is malloc just some type of function pointer to an OS heap implementation?

Comment: `malloc` invokes system calls to provide dynamic memory allocation behavior. In Linux it calls `brk` and `mmap`. So I'd call it an abstraction of system functionality.

Comment: The C library contains a lot of ordinary C code that is precompiled to make it accessible to you, the programmer/user.  Most of that code is not system calls.  The operating system does not implement `malloc()` per se; it provides a mechanism that allows `malloc()` to request more memory, but `malloc()` is responsible for handing out that memory to the program.  So, they are not part of the kernel.  OTOH, the functions in the C library are provided with the operating system, and are used by most programs, so they're very closely related to the operating system.

Comment: Minor point: Most GPL-licensed code has nothing to do with GNU or the free software foundation (except using a license created and publicized by them). Since your system probably uses glibc it actually *is* part of to the GNU project, but (for example) the Linux kernel bears the same GPL header in its source code and headers.

Comment: Ah, I was refer to a notice that said " Copyright (C) 2005, 2007, 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This file is part of the GNU C Library."        At the top of the GPL notice, I suppose I worded that in an odd way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is best asked with another question: what is an Operating System? Or if you prefer: where do you print the line between OS and standard libraries?

Technically, `malloc` is part of the standard C library. And since the Linux is mainly written in C, and that the same library also includes many system calls, not in the C language, it is reasonable to think that this library is part of the OS.

But, on the other hand, there are several implementations of the C library, and also, the GNU C library is available for others operating systems, such as Windows. And I'm sure that there are other languages out there that call the OS *without* using the standard C library. So, from that POV, it is not part of the OS.

But then, Linux is the kernel, the OS should be named GNU/Linux (citation needed). But again, there are Linux systems without GNU, such as Android...

The conclusion is: the term "Operating System" is not a technical one. If you want to be precise, use *kernel* or *standard C library*, etc.

Comment: For this question, I find that considering that Operating System is what happens inside the syscall (in kernel-level code) will suffice.

Comment: @AndréPuel: then `malloc` is not running in kernel-mode, so it is not part of that definition of OS. But it _may_ use OS services to get additional memory, if needed (`brk`, `mmap` or whatever).

Comment: Here you go, [SCO, GNU and Linux](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/sco/sco-gnu-linux) - Stallman. Also, there are a [few additional](http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html) standard C libraries that work on linux.

Answer (score 2):

Yes... and no.  C malloc() is usually a sub-allocator to memory areas provided by OS calls.  The OS manages all virtual memory - that is part of it's job.